# How to change colour of option value in a drop down list

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down list that displays values from a database and I would like to colour code the values in the drop down.  I have managed to do this just fine in browsers on a windows machine but I can't change the colours displayed on a mac.  Is there a way round this?

```
<select id="advice_asked" class="dropdown"  name="advice_asked">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
           <?while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
              if($row['responded'] == 0){
                    $colour = '#63BDFD';
               }else if(($row['response_userID'] == $row['question_userID'])&&($row['response_responded'] == 0)){
                    $colour = '#F68634';
            }?>                     
     <option style="color:<? echo $colour; ?>" value="<? echo $row['questionID']; ?>">
      <? echo $row['questionDesc']; ?> ( Created: <? echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['dateAsked'])); ?>)
     </option>';
        <? } ?>
</select>
```

The dropdown class is

```
.dropdown{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

This has removed most of the styling of the drop down but not the colour.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: simply not a supported option on all platroems

Comment: You can try with a jquery plugin like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for that, back to the drawing board

Comment: Tried playing with `color: rgb(r,g,b)` ?

Comment: @Jari, good idea but doesn't work.

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault, thanks for that, looks promising, I shall try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some plugins like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) or [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) that can help you styling `<select>`